# Objective C - How to return local variable in this code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, methods, local-variables

I have the following code that works.  It successfully displays myName in the NSLog ...

```
NSURL *apiString = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://testapi.com/url"];

[XMLConverter convertXMLURL:apiString completion:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error)
{
    if (success)
    {
        NSString *myName = dictionary[@"profile"][@"real_name"];
        NSLog(@"%@ is my name", myName);
    }
}];
```

I have the following code for the method convertXMLURL which is in XMLConverter.m which I imported.  It does a nice job of converting my XML to NSDictionary.  That is what I want ...

```
+ (void)convertXMLURL:(NSURL *)url completion:(OutputBlock)completion
{
///Wrapper for -initWithContentsOfURL: method of NSXMLParser
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[[XMLConverter new] parser:parser completion:completion];
});
}
```

The problem I have is *dictionary is a local variable.  I need to use it elsewhere in the code.  How can I return it?

Comment: As for the answer below you can declare a Dictionary property either in the .h or .m file, depending on your visibility requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Simply create a `@property` and assign `dictionary` to it inside your `completion handler`.

For example:

## Class Foo

```
@interface Foo : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary* dictionary;

@end
```

## Completion handler

```
NSURL *apiString = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://testapi.com/url"];

[XMLConverter convertXMLURL:apiString completion:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error)
{
    if (success)
    {
        NSString *myName = dictionary[@"profile"][@"real_name"];
        NSLog(@"%@ is my name", myName);
        myInstanceOfFoo.dictionary = dictionary;
    }
}];
```

**EDIT:** If the completion handler is not inside a member of the `Foo` class the `dictionary` property must be declared in the header file (`.h`). Otherwise you can declare it in the implementation file (`.m`).

<sub>Based on the comment by [carlodurso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672895/carlodurso)</sub>